# NavigationLink make a lot of blank spaces

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm currently working on a app ,and I encounter a weird problem , I use NavigationLink like this

```
NavigationLink(
     destination: ContentView(),
      label: {
                  Image(systemName: "house.fill")
         })
```

[This is the View before pressing home and back to the same view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nS3cG.jpg)
I used this `.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)`and `.navigationBarHidden(true)` and
[This is the View after a couple of back and forth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuaF8.jpg) 
I'm curious if anyone encounter this problem and solve this .
It made a weird spacing on top

That didn't work , I delete the `.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)` so you can see what happen if I go to ContentView and back to the same View.
[Going back and forth result in a lot of back buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvPl1.jpg) , ButtonHidden didn't help because just hide the button but the space is still there.

I want my application to have multiple functionality .
one view have a map , one an calendar and one note , for example . If I switch between View that happen , I got a lot of Back button . I want to know if is a solution for that navigationView to disappear and don't stack like that

Comment: Does the ContentView have the NavigstionView? If you keep going “backward and forward” a NavigationView is created every time. You are alt aren’t going “backward and forward” just forward creating a new instance of ContentView each time.

Comment: You only need the NavigationView {} in the first view. If you also have NavigationView multiple views then the others can be removed

Comment: Need some more code to reproduce